# After v2.79, F-Curve handles no longer import from DAE files (including later versions)

Tags: fcurves, dae

I'm writing animations to DAE.
I would like to write Bezier curves with user defined handles/control points.

Seems this is unsupported after Blender v2.79, or there is a new feature which is automatically flattening the Bezier control handles upon import.

I've tested this in versions v2.79, v2.80, v3.0.0, v3.6.8, v4.0.2 (only v2.79 works).
I've also made sure the default handle type is set to free in the settings before importing.

If anyone can help please I'd really appreciate it

[image: Blender v2.79 Correctly Imports Bezier Curve Handles from DAE]
[image: Blender v2.80 Flattens Bezier Curve Handles from DAE]
[image: Here's the Bezier Curve in Question]

Comment: Hi. Bezier curves generally refer to curve objects in the 3D viewport, I believe you meant f-curves for animations. I edited your post to reflect that. If you blieve this was a mistake please reverse the edit

Comment: Thanks for your comment, You're correct, I meant f-curves - those being visible in the graph editor.
hmm good news, It appears I can import the DAE file in Blender v2.79, save the file as a blend file, and then open it in v4.0.2, and the F-Curve Handles are then correct and preserved :)

Comment: Update: I am guessing the issue comes from a blender feature to add a flattened handle/control points automatically for Bézier curves, which is overriding all of the imported handles by accident. Would be fantastic if this could be resolved in the newer versions of blender please?  the other feature I am hoping to see added please is support for is importing quaternion animations from DAE for objects. Planning to give 3DS max a try due to this missing functionality unfortunately.

Comment: Fortunately, I managed to get around this issue through python scripting to write animations to avoid importing animations from DAE :)

Comment: Could you post an answer below detailing how you managed to do that? Maybe a python snippet of the code and a short description of the steps. It may help others withssimilar issues in the future.